# How to know that ES 6 is used in a browser?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading a `React` tutorial. There are notions of `ES` in it. And the version used in the tutorial is `ES` 6. How to know that `ES` 6 is used in a browser ?

Comment: Do you want to know if your browser is compatible with ES6? Or do you want to know if the code is written in ES6?

Comment: I want to know if the browser is compatible with ES6.

Comment: You could use this [link](https://caniuse.com/#search=ECMAScript%202015%20(ES6)) to know if your browser supports ES6 features, and if you are writing code that works on all browsers use a transpiler like babel which will convert es6 code to es5 code that all browsers understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know if your browser is compatible with es6 with this link :

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

ES6 is a "version" of javascript. ES6 brings you more features than ES5.
For example, ES6 allows you to use arrow functions (see [ES6 arrow functions](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies))

If you have an old browser which doesn't support ES6, your application won't work.
But now, most of recent browsers support ES6.